# Populate int[] with random numbers

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

I have made an quiz app which uses a int[] array to set the position of the answers. The array has to be filled with the numbers 0,1,2 and 3, but they have to be randomly placed ( and only occure once). The only way I managed to do it was like this:

```
public int[] castRanInt(){
    int ran_int[] = new int[4];
    Random random = new Random();
    boolean state = true;
    ran_int[0] = random.nextInt(4);
    while (state) {
        for (int r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
            ran_int[r] = random.nextInt(4);
        }
        state = false;
        for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
                if (a == b) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (ran_int[a] == ran_int[b]) {
                    state = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return ran_int;
}
```

The only problem is that this often takes up to 100 runs in the while loop just to populate the array. Is there a simpler / faster way to do this?

Comment: populate the array with `1;2;3;4` and shuffle it. You can shuffle collections with `Collections.shuffle` and there is probably an equivalent for arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found so far:

```
public int[] castRanInt(){
    List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3 });
    Collections.shuffle(intList);

    // Convert List<Integer> to int[]
    int[] ret = new int[intList.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
        ret[i] = intList.get(i);        
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This uses `Collections.shuffle` unfortunately there's no easy way to convert from an `Integer[]` to an `int[]`

Answer (score 0):

Like [Arnaud Denoyelle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371876/populate-int-with-random-numbers#comment60362054_36371876) said you need a list initiated with indices so you can shuffle it

```
public List shuffleArray(int size) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list;
}
```